# Port forwarding working to regular host but not to KVM guest

Tags: iptables, kvm, port-forwarding

I am using port forwarding to bridge two networks, Home (172.16.1.x) and Work (10.x.x.x), for easy access. My Work has also assigned a range to me, 192.168.203.x. There is also some NATing involved.

This iptables setup works for me for a long time, and exists on the linux-based router of the Home network:

```
*nat

# -- NAT configuration.
# ---- Static NAT towards Work
        -I PREROUTING -i vlan7 -d 192.168.203.3 -j DNAT --to 172.16.1.4
        -I POSTROUTING -o vlan7 -s 172.16.1.4 -j SNAT --to 192.168.203.3

# ---- NAT (shared IP) towards the Internet and Work networks.
        -A POSTROUTING -o vlan4 -j MASQUERADE
        -A POSTROUTING -o vlan7 -j MASQUERADE

COMMIT


*filter

# -- Rules for packets coming from Work zone.
# ---- Allow SSH from Work to only some hosts.
        -A INPUT -i vlan7 -s 10.0.6.1 -d 192.168.203.2 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
        -A FORWARD -i vlan7 -s 10.0.6.1 -d 172.16.1.4 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# ---- Allow packets from connections starting from our end.
        -A FORWARD -i vlan7 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
        -A INPUT -i vlan7 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# ---- Log/drop the rest.
        -A INPUT -i vlan7 -j LOG
        -A FORWARD -i vlan7 -j LOG
        -A INPUT -i vlan7 -j DROP
        -A FORWARD -i vlan7 -j DROP
COMMIT
```

This way, I can access ssh on 172.16.1.4 regularly from the Home network where it resides (nothing special here). From the Work network (with my PC on 10.0.6.1) I can access it via the IP 192.168.203.2. All working fine.

However, if I replace that host with a KVM guest (in bridge mode, with its IP set to 172.16.1.4) the following happens:

- I can still access the host from the Home network.
- The host itself can access the Internet and Work networks.
- **I can no longer access it from the Work network.**

So the port forwarding no longer seems to be working. I don't understand how the KVM could be related to this, but maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: As this is a different host, I am now considering that e.g. a firewall running on it may block connections from outside the network.

Comment: Above does not seem to be the case.